# How to change the default GIT branch from cmd

Tags: git, github, branch, default, git-branch

I'm trying to figure out how to change the default git branch from the command line (I know how to do this via the web page, but don't want to automate it using selenium).

The reason I want to do this is because i can't close issues unless the commit is on the default branch.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't do this using the `git` command line, but you can do it using the REST API, so you could write a CLI tool to do this. I've closed this as a dupe of a question that addresses the API aspect of this.

Answer (score 1):

In your public repo this will remap HEAD from master to BRANCH_NAME

`git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/BRANCH_NAME`

Comment: what i'm hoping to do is change the default branch in the settings->Branch option via the command line. Unfortunately this doesn't do that :(

Answer (score -1):

Usually you need to check out your 'default' branch (whatever name it has) and then merge your fixes into it:

```
git commit -m "commit changes in mybranch if i have some"
git checkout 'default-branch' # or whatever name of your default branch is (master?)
git merge 'mybranch' # merge your changes into the default branch
```

Comment: I don't want to merge into my default branch, i ideally just want to close issues over the cmd without it cluttering the history (the closing of issues will be automated)

Comment: if you collaborate with other folks, someone needs to merge your changes eventually in any case.

Comment: i understand that but i don't want the automation to clutter up the history of the branch with just "Closed issue #9"